# How to replace position of string in php?

Tags: php

```
$text = "abc def ghi abc def ghi abc def ghi abc"
$search = "abc";
$regex = '/(\s)'.$search.'(\s)/i';
$array_key = array();
if(preg_match_all($regex, $text, $tmp)) {
    $array_key = $tmp[0];
    $n = count($tmp[0]);
    for($i=0; $i<$n; $i++) {
        if($n % 2 == 0) {
            $content = str_replace($array_key[$i], 'ABC', $text);
        }
}
```

When i echo $content is output:

"`ABC def ghi ABC def ghi ABC def ghi ABC`"

But i want result is "`ABC def ghi abc def ghi ABC def ghi abc`" because `$n % 2 == 0`, How to fix it ?

Comment: `$n` does not change in the loop, so it's either always even or always odd.

Comment: Use `preg_match` instead of `preg_match_all`...currently, it is returning all matches found. `preg_match` will return only the first match.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is str_replace replaces all occurrences of the needle.

Also..must you use a regex?  Have you seen this http://bluedogwebservices.com/replace-every-other-occurrence-with-str_replace/ ?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use `preg_replace_callback`, and a global variable to track iterations. This is the approach taken below.

```
$replacer_i = 0;
function replacer( $matches ) {
  global $replacer_i;
  return $replacer_i++ % 2 === 0 
    ? strtoupper($matches[0]) 
    : $matches[0];
}

$string = "abc def ghi abc def ghi abc def ghi abc";
$string = preg_replace_callback( "/abc/", "replacer", $string );

// ABC def ghi abc def ghi ABC def ghi abc
print $string;
```

Another approach would be to split the string, and replace every other instance of "abc" with its uppercase form, then glue the parts back together into a new string:

```
$string = "abc def ghi abc def ghi abc def ghi abc";
$aparts = explode( " ", $string );
$countr = 0;

foreach ( $aparts as $key => &$value ) {
  if ( $value == "abc" && ( $countr++ % 2 == 0 ) ) {
    $value = strtoupper( $value );
  }
}

// ABC def ghi abc def ghi ABC def ghi abc
print implode( " ", $aparts );
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$text = "abc def ghi abc def ghi abc def ghi abc";
$search = "ghi";
$regex = '/('.$search.')(.*)/i';
$array_key = array();
if(preg_match($regex, $text, $tmp)) {
    $c = strtoupper($tmp[1]);
    $content = str_replace( $tmp[1] . $tmp[2], $c .  $tmp[2], $tmp[0] );
    $content = str_replace( $tmp[1] . $tmp[2], $content, $text );
}

echo $content;
?>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why the downvote, i think it does what is asked for. Any reasons please...would help me to identify the issue.